# Inverting Amplifiers LM308

Tags: operational-amplifier, homework, inverting-amplifier

I was required to draw a schematic diagram of inverting amplifiers using LM308 Op-amp in LTSpice. I need to connect +ve power supply to 10V and -ve power supply to -10V, a feedback resistor of 10k ohm and input resistor to set the gain to -10.I'm totally new to the op amp and LTSpice. Can i know whether im doing it correct or not?
[image: LM308Op amp]

Comment: You can do a google image search for 'inverting op-amp' and find the answer for yourself in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You have some of the correct components on there, and the supplies (voltage sources) would be correct if the other side of them was grounded. Personally, I would prefer the negative supply be flipped so the negative side connects to the op-amp and set to +10, but it's okay the way you have it.

However those voltage source grounds are missing, the op-amp inputs/resistors are not connected in an inverting amplifier configuration, the input voltage is shorted to ground, there are no frequency compensation components on the op-amp (see the datasheet for the latter- external frequency compensation, if required, varies with op-amp type and application).